# How to deploy and access Dropwizard app

Tags: java, rest, server, dropwizard

I'm struggling with running Dropwizard app on Ubuntu.

When I run this fat jar on my local cli everything work fine as the url is `http://localhost:8080/hellow-world` but I have no clue how to set the access point in Ubuntu running online.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the hostname of your server by executing

```
$ hostname -f
```

in the shell. Use the result instead of `localhost` in the URL.